# Creating undirected graphs in Python

Tags: python, graph

I need to create a program that analyzes the traveling salesman problem using Python. Does anyone know of a good resource that will help me learn how to create and use undirected graphs in Python? Any info that may help me with the TSP would be greatly appreciated as well.

Comment: This might help: http://www.python.org/doc/essays/graphs/ Or: http://code.google.com/p/python-graph/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About Python library for directed and undirected graphs, you can take a look at [igraph](http://igraph.sourceforge.net/) or [NetworkX](http://networkx.lanl.gov/).

As for the TSP, a little googling indicates that some Python code and discussion is available [here](http://www.psychicorigami.com/2007/04/10/tackling-the-travelling-salesman-problem-prologue/), and some background is given in these slides, [A Short History of the Traveling Salesman Problem](http://neumann.hec.ca/chairedistributique/common/laporte-short.pdf), and on this page, [Traveling Salesman Problem](http://iris.gmu.edu/~khoffman/papers/trav_salesman.html).