# python tsp travelling salesman undirected graph

Tags: python, graph, networkx, traveling-salesman

In other posts Networkx was suggested as "my friend". But there doesn't seem to be a ready to use function for a certain solution for the TSP problem. 
i.e. [Creating undirected graphs in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6197339/creating-undirected-graphs-in-python)

I have an undirected graph, the suggested solutions are all related to directed graphs, and I want to know a short tour to visit all nodes using the available edges.

(also, the tsp with directed graphs I could not find in the documentation of networkx)

Does anybody did something like this for an undirected graph or should I modify solutions for directed graphs with infinit costs for unconnected nodes?

edit: I am learning: Actually, as the graph is unweighted (or 'all weights' are the same), and not every node is connected to all other nodes,  I just need to find a cycle in the graph containing all the nodes. When that cycle does not exist, nodes may be repeated (so, it is not a cycle anymore...). There are no isolated groups (there is a path from each node to another). I think that this is not the salesman problem?!

Thanks for your feedback so far (when milliseconds start to matter, I will install a photofinish :) )

Comment: undirected graph `G_1` is directed graph `G_2` with edges `(v,w)` and `(w,v)` for every `(v,w) in E(G_1)`

Comment: @zenpoy: You beat me to it by bare seconds

Comment: @inspectorG4dget - I hate when that happens!

Answer (score 2):

If you already have code for directed graphs, I would just convert your undirected graph. Replace each undirected edge with two directed edges, one in each direction, preserving the edge weight.